# float2 extension error, self used before stored properties initialised?

Tags: swift

I was looking back at a project that I did in `Xcode 7.0 beta 3 (7A152u)` where I used the following `extension` to add a `CGPoint` initialiser to `float2`. **(The code below is identical to that used in the WWDC2015 demo project DemoBots)** Back in late July this worked fine, but now using `Xcode 7.0 GM (7A218)` I am getting the error:

```
TEST.swift:32:11: 'self' used before all stored properties are initialized
```

I have looked at the various release notes but can't find anything relevant, can anyone help me out or point me in the right direction as to why this is now failing and maybe how to fix it?

```
// Extend `float2` to add an initializer from a `CGPoint`.
extension float2 {
// MARK: Initialization

    /// Initialize with a `CGPoint` type.
    init(_ point: CGPoint) {
        x = Float(point.x) // << Above Error Here
        y = Float(point.y) // << Above Error Here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is fixed if you use:

```
init(_ point: CGPoint) {
    self = float2(x: Float(point.x), y: Float(point.y))
}
```

or

```
init(_ point: CGPoint) {
    self.init(x: Float(point.x), y: Float(point.y))
}
```

or, as pointed out by Martin R:

```
init(_ point: CGPoint) {
    self.init()
    x = Float(point.x)
    y = Float(point.y)
}
```

The second way is used in the `float2` extension in the [latest DemoBots project](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/samplecode/DemoBots/Listings/Swift_GeometryExtensions_swift.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015179-Swift_GeometryExtensions_swift-DontLinkElementID_57).

As said by Stephen Canon in his comment below, this works because: in the WWDC seed, the simd structs had native scalars as components, so initializing this way worked. In later seeds, the simd structs are backed by a LLVM builtin vector, and the components `x`, `y`, etc are just `{ get set }` computed properties.

Comment: It would be interesting to know *why* the code from the question does not compile. A similar extension for `CGPoint` instead of `float2` compiles without problems.

Comment: @MartinR: In the WWDC seed, the simd structs had native scalars as components, so initializing this way worked.  In later seeds, the simd structs are backed by a LLVM builtin vector, and the components `x`, `y`, etc are just `{ get set }` computed properties.

Comment: I just swapped it to this `self.goalAgent.position = float2(Float(position.x), Float(position.y))` but as Martin R says I was more curious what had changed as I am also using the CGPoint extension which compiles fine and is virtually identical in its construction.

Comment: @StephenCanon: Thanks, that seems to explain it. – Calling `self.init()` before assigning the properties would also work.

Comment: @ABakerSmith: May I suggest that you add the explanation to the answer itself (with an attribution to the comment). That would make the answer self-contained, and comments are sometimes deleted.

Comment: Thank you everyone, much appreciated.